# How to change the image on the MGSwipeButton in MGSwipeTableCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTYcx.jpg)

```
   -(nullable NSArray<UIView*>*) swipeTableCell:(nonnull MGSwipeTableCell*) cell swipeButtonsForDirection:(MGSwipeDirection)direction
                               swipeSettings:(nonnull MGSwipeSettings*) swipeSettings expansionSettings:(nonnull MGSwipeExpansionSettings*) expansionSettings {
    swipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition3D; // 滑出动画
    if (direction == MGSwipeDirectionRightToLeft) {
        expansionSettings.fillOnTrigger = YES;
               expansionSettings.threshold = 1.5;
               CGFloat padding = 10;
               MGSwipeButton *isTop = [MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"" icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top"] backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243/256.0 green:243/256.0 blue:243/256.0 alpha:1] padding:padding callback:^BOOL(MGSwipeTableCell *sender) {
                   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
                   TrackNumbersCellModel*model = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
                   if (model.isTop) {
                      
                       model.isTop = NO;
                       [self.dataSource removeObject:model];
                       [self.dataSource insertObject:model atIndex:self.dataSource.count - 1];
                       [[TrackNumbersNetTools shareIntance] trackTable_MR_update_top_Entity:model.t_number isTop:NO];
                       [self.tableView reloadData];
                       
                   }else{
                       model.isTop = YES;
                       [self.dataSource removeObject:model];
                       [self.dataSource insertObject:model atIndex:0];
                       [[TrackNumbersNetTools shareIntance] trackTable_MR_update_top_Entity:model.t_number isTop:YES];
                       [self.tableView reloadData];
                   }
                   
                   return YES;
               }];
               [isTop centerIconOverTextWithSpacing:7];
               
               MGSwipeButton *isDelete = [MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"" icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delet"] backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243/256.0 green:243/256.0 blue:243/256.0 alpha:1] padding:padding callback:^BOOL(MGSwipeTableCell *sender) {
                   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
                   TrackNumbersCellModel*model = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
                   [self.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                   [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
                   [[TrackNumbersNetTools shareIntance] trackTable_MR_deleteEntity:model.t_number onFinished:^{
                       if (self.deleteBlock) {
                           self.deleteBlock();
                       }
                   }];
                  
                   return YES;
               }];
               [isDelete centerIconOverTextWithSpacing:7];
               return @[isTop,isDelete];
    }
    
    return nil;
    
}
```

My problem is that when I click on the "isTop" MGSwipeButton. I tried to change the image on the MGSwipeButton and used the following method, but it didn't work. Please help.
With a link to "MGSwipeTableCell":https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

```
-(BOOL)swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*)cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL)fromExpansion{
    if (direction == MGSwipeDirectionRightToLeft && index == 0) {
        id button = cell.leftButtons[index];
        MGSwipeButton * pressedBtn = button;
        [pressedBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yy"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"pressedBtn title: %@",pressedBtn.titleLabel.text);}
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You question is unclear. According to provided link you need to change Image of left and right swipe cell in cellForRowAt function. But you are changing it in tappedButtonAtIndex that's why you image is not getting change. 

Do you want to change the image when cell get's swipe or what?

Comment: When the slide out button to the left appears, change the picture after clicking the button with the red circle drawn on it.